# How to make HTML code more readable?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 5 buttons that are coded on 1 single line. This allows me to squeeze them next to each other without any spaces in between, which is what I want.

However, if I move the code for each button down one line, there are spaces in between the buttons, which is what I don't want.

Here is the sample code for 2 buttons:

```
<button id="home" type="button">Home</button><button id="save" type="button">Save
</button><button id="create" type="button">Create</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, did he break single-responsibility-question pattern? one question in a question is not part of [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).. cmiiw

Comment: I have re-edited my question to contain 1 question now.

Comment: @YuliamChandra: It probably should be added there.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/157247

Comment: Personally, I minify my HTML on-the-fly in PHP, so I can write with as much space as I want, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your buttons with a class:

```
<button class="button" id="save">Save</button>
<button class="button" id="new">New</button>
<button class="button" id="load">Load</button>
```

Create a class in the CSS file:

```
.button {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px; /*For example*/
}
```

That will make your buttons stick together without spaces, and HTML will be more readable.

EDIT: As you use an ID, add that ID in your CSS class with a margin-left.

```
/* in this example, the button to the mostleft is #save, so...*/
#save {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fef2Z/)

Comment: quick question, if I wanted to just pad the left-most button to the right some pixels, how would I do that in the class without affecting the padding for all the buttons?

Answer (score 2):

You could put the newline character inside your tags:

```
<button>btn1</button
><button>btn2</button
><button>btn3</button>
```

You can comment out the space between your tags so it's as if the space wasn't even there.

```
<button id="home" type="button">Home</button><!--
--><button id="save" type="button">Save</button><!--
--><button id="create" type="button">Create</button>
```

As for the CSS, CSS lets you define attributes for multiple classes/ids/etc at the same time.

```
#save, #home {
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 240px;
}
#home { margin-left: 40px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "class" attribute of the input element to define styling options which are influencing all the buttons that got the class. Let me show you:

```
<button id="home" type="button" class="btn-style">Home</button>
<button id="save" type="button" class="btn-style">Save</button>
<button id="create" type="button" class="btn-style">Create</button>
```

And in your css you have the stylings:

```
.btn-style{
//your css here
}
```

To have no space between the buttons you simply use CSS styling. But for that make, search at google. You may need styling attributes like "display, margin, float...".

Greetz

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's pretty irritating that HTML does this but the way I solve it is as follows:

```
<button>btn1</button
><button>btn2</button
><button>btn3</button
><button>btn4</button
><button>btn5</button>
```

Or as other users are also suggesting, you can insert comments in-between:

```
<button>btn1</button><!--
--><button>btn2</button><!--
--><button>btn3</button><!--
--><button>btn4</button><!--
--><button>btn5</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem of spaces between inline-elements such as `<button>`, try to write the code like that :

```
<button id="home" type="button">Home</button><!--
--><button id="save" type="button">Save</button><!--
--><button id="create" type="button">Create</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply common css by `button` selector and any specific styles by their **ids**

```
button{
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 240px;
}
#home{
    margin-left: 40px;
}
#save{

}
```